# Is there a faster version of Skype for Android?

Tags: skype

The [latest version of Android](https://blogs.skype.com/news/2017/06/01/introducing-the-next-generation-of-skype) is painfully slow - on my Sony Z3 it is nearly impossible to use. The previous version were also annoyingly slow and took up a lot of space.

Is there an alternative version of Skype that is more convenient to use?

Comment: I don't know how to address this. Self-answered questions are allowed here, of course, but this seems to be advertising, ala Spam. This is not allowed - see Help for that which is considered spam. This also seems to be phrased as a recommendation for an application, which we also do not allow. See the Help for that which is considered off-topic. I seem to have written myself a justification for a Vote to Close.

Comment: @wbogacz I do not work for Microsoft and you can see I'm a long-standing Stackexchange member. Given that Skype is one of the top 10 applications worldwide (and Skype Lite is it's official version for certain markets) I don't think it needs any extra advertisement. Also, this isn't an app recommendation - it's a recommendation for users who already use Skype. Please roll back your close vote.

Comment: OK. I'll rollback my VTC. But I'm leaving the comment, since I still consider this a questionable post. Others can decide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is! In February 2017 Microsoft introduced a new version of their app called [Skype Lite](https://www.skype.com/en/skype-lite/), which is a lot faster. According to the official page the new version is:

> Lightweight, battery-friendly and runs smoothly on new and old Android mobile devices.

Since sometime in 2018 it became available to all users worldwide, so you can install it directly from the Play Store.

*NB: I do not work for Microsoft and have nothing to do with the development of this app.*

Comment: Upvoted please remember to add such disclaimer

Comment: Worth to note that Skype Lite is not available for all Android devices. Google Play states it's not available for my Nokia 5.3, which is a shame because vanilla Skype runs horribly slow on it. I did not find any proper statement via websearch on which devices are supported and which ones are not. :-(

Comment: @AttilaCsipak doesn't work if you directly install the .apk?

Comment: That may be OK for someone who wants to invest time into looking up a trustable source, playing around with a custom installation and also installing updates manually later. That's generally not me.